# How can I change code style according to this screenshot in Android Studio so my line of code don't go farther than the screen width

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

**I want to change my code style settings in Android Studio for Windows as Shown in this Figure, So my code does not go out of device width. And show these arrows for next line as in Figure...???**

**

> I'm Using Android Studio 4.0.1 on Windows-10

**

[image: I want to change my code style settings in Android Studio for Windows as Shown in this Figure, So my code does not go out of device width. And show these arrows for next line as in Figure...???]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your **toolbar ->  View -> Active Editor -> Soft-wrap** (uncheck it)

With Soft wrap (ignore gibberish text for testing):
[image]

Without Soft wrap :

[image]

Not using windows but I think view settings would be the same regardless of OS